# from Javascript to Python on click

Tags: javascript, django, highcharts

I'm working on a feature for a heatmap. When I click on a cell in the chart, a boxplot will pop up, and I am using django and highcharts models for the implementation.

Currently, I am stuck with the passing of variable from a javascript function to the python server side. I know for django there is a post and get method, but I don't have a form in this case, only the clicks. Whenever I click on a cell in the heatmap, I would like to pass the x-label and y-label strings to the python server, process and grab data in python, and then feed the data back to the pop-up boxplot. Thank you !

```
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
        events:{
        click: function cellClick() {
            var $div = $('<div></div>')
            .dialog({
                 title: this.name,
                 width: 400,
                 height: 300
            });

            window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                 chart: {
                 renderTo: $div[0],
                 type: 'boxplot'
            },

            series: [{
                 name: 'Observations',
                 data: [
              //here I would like to insert data passed from the python view 
              // on click of a cell in the heatmap
                  ],
             }, {
                name: 'Outliers',
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
                type: 'scatter',
                data: [//data from python view],
             }]
           })
                }
            }
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        opposite: true,
        categories: label,
        labels:{
                formatter: function(){
                //I would like to pass factor_x to the server(python) on click
                //of a cell in the heatmap
                    var factor_x = this.value;

                    if (factor_x.length > 6){
                        return factor_x.substr(0,6) ;
                    }else{
                         return factor_x;  
                      }
                }
            },
    },


    yAxis: {
        categories: label2,
        labels:{
                formatter: function(){
                // pass factor_y to the server side on-click
                    var factor_y = this.value;
                    if (factor_y.length > 7){
                        return factor_y.substr(0,7) + "...";
                    }else{
                         return factor_y;
                    }
                }
            },
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Factor Correlation',
        data: correlation,
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: Look up AJAX to understand how you can send GET requests in pure Javascript. You don't need a form to do this. :) You can then create an `onClick` event handler that fires off an AJAX GET request when the chart is pressed. See [an example with jQuery for a button click](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp).

Comment: POST and GET are http requests, they have nothing to do with forms other than forms use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so what you can do is write click functions for the cells of heatmaps.

In the onclick functions, you'll get the value of that cell by using the "this" variable in javascript, as it tells you what container or DOM element you clicked.

So now $(this).data or whatever attribute of that element has the required information (which you can check in your browser on your console by inspecting element) will give you the data you want to send to your views so that you can manipulate it.

So for that you'll call another function say send_data() from this onclick function and you'll pass this required information to that function maybe as one or two variables or as a list like this:

```
send_data(info);
```

where info is a list of all the required elements.

Now inside the send_data function you'll make an ajax call to the URL corresponding to the class or def in your views to which you want to supply this information like this:

```
function send_data(req_info) {

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/heatmap_cell_data/",
       data: req_info,
       // dataType: 'json',

       success: function(response){ 
            console.log(response);
       }
    });
}
```

Now in your urls.py you'll associate a def/class in views corresponding to the URL in your Ajax function. You'll receive this data in request.POST, then you'll do whatever you want to in that view and finally return an HTTPResponse(whatever data you want to) back to the javascript which you'll receive as response in your success function.

NOTE -> Sending an HTTPRespnse from views.py back to the Ajax request is a must or else you'll get an error that no HTTPResponse found.

Now you can use this response data to modify your heatmaps again.

I hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: And you also need the CSRF part when using POST method as specified by @cardonator

Answer (score 0):

The most secure way to handle this with Django is to pass the CSRF token along with each AJAX request you post data within. The easiest way to do this is to put this on your page (it appears you are using jQuery so this should work as is):

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: false, // obviates need for sameOrigin test
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

What this does is grab the CSRF cookie that Django typically stores on the browser when someone accesses a form and send it along with the AJAX requests.

This means you will also need something like this on the page somewhere:

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

On your view function, you will want the `csrf_protect` decorator. You can also use `require_post` to only accept POST data on this view:

```
@require_post
@csrf_protect
def my_view(request):
    pass
```

The most ideal way to handle the functionality you are looking for is when you need a plot, post it to a view like the above and then have another view for getting the latest results. This will also work better if multiple people can mess with it at the same time.

In jQuery that would mean [using something like](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/):

```
$.post('/my_view/', some_json_data);
```

And to collect the data you would use:

```
$.get('/my_view_updates/', success: somefunctiontoparseresponse);
```